# Parsing result from getline

Tags: c++, c++14

I am using `getline` to read in input from standard input line by line but am interested in looking at each word of the line I receive from `getline` individually.

What is the best solution to achieve this?  I was thinking about putting the string into a `stringstream` and then parsing through that but was wondering if there was a more effective solution or if this would even work.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: If you are interested in reading each word, why would you get line in the first place? Just simple cin >> string, and it'll read until a space.... no need for parsing

Comment: I need to get the entire line since each line contains a set of command that go together.  Each line needs to be distinct from the set.  The goal is to implement SQL style commands using C++

Comment: Best way would be to post an example. If you really just want to read a line and parse it, if you use getline it will store the line in a string, from there you can use some loop to read each word by checking for spaces and do whatever you need with the word.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use the boost libraries then some of the string algorithms could be useful here to tokenize the line into words.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/trim.hpp>

std::vector<std::string> split(std::string value,
                               const std::string& delims) {
    std::vector<std::string> parts;
    boost::trim_if(value, boost::is_any_of(delims));
    boost::split(parts, value,
                 boost::is_any_of(delims), boost::token_compress_on);
    return parts;
}

int main(int, char**) {
    for (size_t lines = 1; !std::cin.eof(); ++lines) {
        std::string input_line;
        std::getline(std::cin, input_line);
        std::vector<std::string> words = split(input_line, " ");
        for (const std::string& word : words) {
            std::cout << "LINE " << lines << ": " << word << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
$ printf "test  foo   bar\n a b c \na b c" | ./a.out 
LINE 1: test
LINE 1: foo
LINE 1: bar
LINE 2: a
LINE 2: b
LINE 2: c
LINE 3: a
LINE 3: b
LINE 3: c
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use 'string.c_str()[index]' to get each word in string.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
    string sIn;

    // input 
    getline(cin,sIn);

    for (int i=0 ; i<sIn.length() ; i++ ) {
        // get one char from sIn each time
        char c = sIn.c_str()[i];

        // insert something you want to do 
        // ...

        cout << c << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Get each word in a string then store it in char? Doesn't make sense.